# Geoserver ECQL Intersects returns empty result

Tags: geoserver

I am trying to understand ECQL and the intersects filter.
This filter entered on the geoserver layer preview returns my WMS as ecpected

```
Intersects(the_geom,POINT(1916881.37823 5762168.62373))
```

Now I try to use this filter on a URL to retrieve the WFS for the feature:

```
http://myserver/fwsys/wms?service=WFS&version=1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=fwsys:fwsys_region&CQL_FILTER=Intersects(the_geom,POINT(1916881.37823%205762168.62373))
```

The browser returns this result

```
<wfs:FeatureCollection xsi:schemaLocation="http://fire.niwa.co.nz/fwsys_region http://gs-test.niwa.co.nz/fwsys/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeName=fwsys%3Afwsys_region http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd">
    <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:null>unknown</gml:null>
    </gml:boundedBy>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

Instead of my expected WFS...

I have tried the same URL but with a polygon filter and it worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Updated this questions wuth details about the layer.

The layer I am trying to use is in EPSG:2193

```
PROJCS["NZGD2000 / New Zealand Transverse Mercator 2000",
    GEOGCS["NZGD2000",
        DATUM["New Zealand Geodetic Datum 2000",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980", 6378137.0, 298.257222101, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            TOWGS84[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6167"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295],
        AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST],
        AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4167"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","9807"]],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian", 173.0],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor", 0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting", 1600000.0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing", 10000000.0],
    UNIT["m", 1.0],
    AXIS["Easting", EAST],
    AXIS["Northing", NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","2193"]]
```

Comment: I can only say that this seems to work `http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&TypeName=topp:states&CQL_FILTER=Intersects(the_geom,POINT(-99%2032))`

Comment: most likely issue is mixing projections - we'd need to know more about your layer to be sure.

Comment: Thanks to you both for responding. I updated the question with the map details... Thanks, Uwe

Comment: @user30184 Following your link I see an error msg Could not parse CQL filter list.
Lexical error at line 1, column 6.  Encountered:

Comment: Copy-paste is just messing up the text. Try this way http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&TypeName=topp:states&CQL_FILTER=Intersects(the_geom,POINT(-99%2032))

Comment: @user30184:
Thank you so much! You just made my day! Works like a treat. If you officially answer the question I will accept it!

Comment: Did it somehow help you with your own server?

Comment: Yes it did, so that's really good. Now am facing my next issue that I need to project coordindate from EPSG:3875 into EPSG:2193. That does not work (yet). Will create a new question for that,
Thanks

Comment: With that filter: Can I specify what the SRS (name) is?
I was hoping for something like this
myserver?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&srsName=EPSG:2193&request=GetFeature&typeName=fwsys:fwsys_region&CQL_FILTER=Intersects(the_geom,POINT(174.76  -37.18,'EPSG:4326))